# Clone usb sata to usb sata

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, linux-mint, clonezilla, usb-to-sata

I have a Linux machine running mint, I have an external USB SATA drive, which is recognized by the Linux system. What I’m trying to achieve is a clone of the external USB SATA to another external USB SATA. I have Clonezilla on a USB, was wondering if I could achieve what I’m trying to do with Clonezilla, if so would it be device to device rather than image to device, however if Clonezilla won’t work, how would I go about doing it

Comment: If the devices are of the same size and there is no problem with logical sector size mismatch (compare [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511256/108618)) then it can be as easy as `cp /dev/sdx /dev/sdy` or `</dev/sdx pv >dev/sdy` (not necessarily optimal though). You said "wondering if I could achieve what I’m trying to do with Clonezilla". What keeps you from trying with Clonezilla then?

Comment: well its just i have always used clonezilla to clone an image from the local disk to and external usb drive, however i have never attempted to clone anything from an usb external device to another usb external device, was worried i might do something wrong or it wouldnt work.

Comment: Also i wasnt sure in how to do that, as i follow youtube links in how to do an image clone.  i was just assuming it was device to device, is that still the correct way? also if anyone can recommend a link i could follow to do what im trying to do, would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an image of your drive using dd, which is a command line tool, but can be launched directly from a running system.

To duplicate drive a to drive b, simply type

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

That is the simple part.

Unfortunately, it duplicates completely the drive… even the partition table, and all metadata.

You can also create a partition on your target drive the exact same size as the source partition, and use

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1
```

to only copy the first primary partition of first disk on first primary partition on second disk.

So, if your target drive is significantly bigger than source drive, you will still have some available space on it to create a second partition, or extend the duplicated one with another tool.

If you want another solution than a physical duplication, for exemple to deal with disks of different sizes from source to destination, you’d better consider simple copy tools, like tar or rsync.

Explain your needs a little bit significantly, so you may have some more help.